# Better way to use .replace and .strip? Python

Tags: python

Hi Id like to know if I can tidy up my code any better than I have.

Basically the answer would be something like`x = "£1,094.99    "`
Im using `x.strip()` and `x.strip("£")` and `x.replace(",")` and then `x = float(x) * 1.18` to convert figure into euros.

Any way to make this more efficient? Im a newbie so i just wondered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

a nice one liner i use quite often is this:

```
x = ''.join([c for c in x if c in '1234567890.'])
```

So something like this:

```
x = "$1,094.99"
x = ''.join([c for c in x if c in '1234567890.'])
print x
```

will give you an output of:

```
1094.99
```

Then you can use your float(x) * 1.18 as you have been. I find this to be a good method as it is some what robust. stray characters and dollar signs instead of pound signs shouldn't stop it from working.

Comment: @alienware13user Its basically looking at all of the characters in the string x (c for c in x) and if that character is in the string '1234567890.' then it returns that character. otherwise it skips it.

Comment: Ah thanks -I know Im not meant to comment thanks. but thanks :P

Comment: @alienware13user no worries, i think it was a good question as you've got three different answers all of which are right for different scenarios. Whelp, one of them dissappeared. Still an interesting question though.

Answer (score 5):

you can replace it to ''

```
float(data.replace(',','').replace('£',''))*1.18
```

Comment: This answer is nice as well, i think it is better than mine if you want to make sure only the pound and commas are replaced but worse if you want to strip any currency symbol. Also i imagine some people would find the replace syntax easier to read than the "x for x in..."

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not using .split, but i always find for problem where you want to **grab all non-delimiter strings** (numbers in this case), it's worth using regex. You just need to find non-white or '.'

```
import re
x = "£1,094.99 "
number = float(''.join(re.findall('\w+|\.',s)))
euro = number * 1.18
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this elegantly using `re` and `decimal` module, like this :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from re import sub
from decimal import Decimal
x = "£1,094.99" 
value = Decimal(sub(r'[^\d.]', '', x))
print(value)
value_euro = float(value) * 1.18
print(value_euro)
```

This will result in :

```
1094.99
1292.0882
```